# What's the best place to put a live chat?

Tags: chat

I know that this question has been asked couple of time already. But the situation is a bit different.

Indeed we already have icon for feedback on our website (that I can easily move where I want), and we'd like to add a Live Chat function.

In that particular case, what would be the best places for each features?

Thanks

Comment: How is it different? We can't know what your circumstances are (if your case is that much different from all the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

At a first point user should understand where the live chat window is.

1. Live chat window should be kept minimised.
2. Should be on all the pages
3. Usually at the bottom right, so it doesn't obstruct the user from what he is looking for on the page
4. Popup window on the landing page to show where the live chat is and the pop up show fades away in limited time. (This feature is application dependent and also depends on the user hits for the live chat)
5. The close window and minimise window will have same logic ideally